# PHP Проверка на существование картинки по ссылке, в противном случае искать дальше

Tags: php

Припустим есть массив:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string() "Нерабочая ссылка на картинку"
  [1]=>
  string() "Рабочая ссылка на картинку"
...
}
```

Нужно начать его перебор, в случае если картинке по ссылке не существует - пропускать и идти дальше, если существует то вывести сохранить на сервере (copy).

Comment: Удобнее будет распарралелить это, нежели чем ждать окончания каждой проверки линейно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю нужно копать в сторону ***file_get_contents***, что-то типа: делать перебор массива до тех пор, пока возвращаемое значение функцией будет отлично от false - это и будет картинка.

Документация - **http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php**

Пример:

```
foreach($links as $link){ 
    if(($result = file_get_contents($link)) !== false){ 
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно пример? Я не совсем понимаю как сделать такой перебор, который продолжает перебирать дальше в случае false

Comment: foreach($links as $link){
  if(($result = file_get_contents($link)) !==  false){
     break;
  }
}
Примерно так

Comment: @АндрейДобровольский, вы можете нажать "править" и добавить свой код в ответ